# Cats Validated returns input if validation passed, without over mapping

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I do [validation](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/validated.html) of a form. Imagine we want to validate some subset of the  `Cat` case class fields:

```
case class Cat(name: String, age: Int, weight: Double)

def validateCatName(name: String): ValidationResult[String]
def validateCatAge(age: Int): ValidationResult[Int]

def validateCatForm(cat: Cat): ValidationResult[Cat] = {
    (validateCatName(cat.name),
    validateCatAge(cat.age)
    ).mapN((_, _) => cat)
  }
```

I can not get idea of `mapN((r1, ..., rN) => Result(r1, ..., rN))`. 
For example in my case I have to do `mapN((validatedName, validatedAge) => Cat(validatedName, validatedAge, cat.weight)`.
Actually I want to ignore the validated results and escape some over re-mapping with the dumb params. Something like this:

```
def validateCatForm(cat: Cat): ValidationResult[Cat] = {
        (validateCatName(cat.name),
        validateCatAge(cat.age)
        ).ifValid(cat)
      }
```

Is it possible?

Comment: what did you finally go for ?

Answer (score 3):

You can ignore the arguments and return the `cat` directly:

```
def validateCatForm(cat: Cat): ValidationResult[Cat] = {
  (
    validateCatName(cat.name),
    validateCatAge(cat.age)
  ).mapN{ (_, _) => cat }
}
```

However, recall that it is usually the job of the constructor to ensure that every constructed `Cat` is actually valid. The `validateCatForm` should rather be accepting `name` and `age` directly, then you could write:

```
def validateCatForm(name: String, age: Int): ValidationResult[Cat] = {
  (
    validateCatName(name),
    validateCatAge(age)
  ).mapN{ new Cat(_, _) }
}
```

In this way, you would not force the users of your API to create any invalid `Cat`s just in order to pass them to a form validation method.

Comment: I use [circle](https://circe.github.io/circe/codec.html) library to unmarshalling(decode) an akka request. On this step I can rely that I receive all required fields which are right typed: `POST[Json] -> Entity`. After that I apply form validation to bring some BL validations rules. For example a name should be at least X characters or password enough secured. I do not think decoders should be aware of this BL rules.

Comment: Then you might want to declare two separate kinds of cats of various levels of purity, e.g. `UnmarshalledCat` vs. `ValidatedBLCat`. Otherwise, someone, somewhere, will forget to call `validateCatForm`, and an unsanitized invalid cat will escape from the unmarshalling stage and wreak havoc elsewhere. Specifically about `ifValid`: there doesn't seem to be any similar method (see [boilerplate generator](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/project/Boilerplate.scala)), and adding new methods to all tuples is somewhat of a pain, so taking `mapN` and skipping args seems the simplest way.